How to handle the area calculation when the integral of √x ​ is not defined for part of the interval?
I am trying to calculate the area between two curves: $y = x +5$ and $y^2 = x$.
After rewriting $y^2=x$ as $y = \sqrt{x}
$​, I realized that $\sqrt{x}$
​ is not defined for $x<0$. What should I do to calculate the area in this case?
So far, I have considered splitting the interval into parts where the functions are defined:

For [−1,0] only $y=x+5$ seems valid.
For [0,2] both $y= \sqrt{x}$
​ and $y=x+5$ are valid.

Then I integrated the respective functions over their valid domains and summed the resulting areas, obtaining $$A = \frac {99 - 8\sqrt{2}} {6}$$ However, my professor's solution states that the final result is: $$\frac {33}{2}$$
What am I missing here?
Thank you for your help!

That picture also mentions the lines $y=2$ and $y=-1$, but you did not mention them. Why is that?

Write down the set of which you want to calculate the area from in the form ${(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ \dots \ }$. Then it should be easier.

Writing $y=\sqrt{x}$ is just one of the curves: you also need $y=-\sqrt{x}$. The question seems to look for the area, rather than the signed area, so you have to do the above and below axis parts separately. You can integrate with $x$, but there are several bits to it, as you say: in $[-1, 0]$ you ignore the $y^2=x$ part. There are fewer bits if you integrate with $y$:
$$ \int_{-1}^2 dy\,y^2 -(y-5) = \left[\frac13y^3 - \frac12y^2+5y\right]_{-1}^2 = \frac{33}2$$
Note that $y=x+5\implies x=y-5$ and I took the negative of that to get the area (rather than the signed area), taking care that $y=x+5$ doesn't cross the $y$ axis for $y\in[-1,2]$.
I prefer to do it a different way, calculating the $x<0$ part as a trapezium, i.e. area is base times average height: $\frac12 3\times(6+3)=\frac{27}2$, and the $x\ge0$ part as $ \int_{-1}^2 dy\,y^2 = 3$, to get $\frac{27}2 + 3 = \frac{33}2$.
